# Constructor must be fully assigned

Tags: c#, list, struct

```
public struct S_Matrix
{
    public int size_C,size_R;
    public List<entries_R> entry_R;

    public S_Matrix(int c, int r)
    {
        this.size_C = c;
        this.size_R = r;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix it. When I add default value to the List, it fixes the problem but I can't simply instantiate a value in struct.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a `struct`.

Comment: `public S_Matrix(int c, int r):this(){}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct field `entry_R` is not getting initialized. In a struct, every member has to be initialized in the constructor. If you don't want this behavior, you might want to use a simple class.

```
 public struct S_Matrix
 {
     public int size_C, size_R;
     public List<entries_R> entry_R;

     public S_Matrix(int c, int r, List<entries_R> en)
     {
         this.size_C = c;
         this.size_R = r;
         this.entry_R = en;
         // If you don't want a constructor parameter:
         // this.entry_R = null;
         // or:
         // this.entry_R = new List<entries_R>();
     }
 }
```

In most cases, a class is what you want. Structs should only be used if one knows what one is doing.

```
 public class S_Matrix
 {
     public int size_C, size_R;
     public List<entries_R> entry_R;

     public S_Matrix(int c, int r)
     {
         this.size_C = c;
         this.size_R = r;
         // entry_R keeps being uninitialised
     }
 }
```